# "QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped" when adding an entity from another package

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I've made a Hibernate configuration maven project (built with the maven-shade-plugin) to allow my codebase to use one unified "database class". However, the class does not seem to map (throws a `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped` exception at runtime) when called from outside the running project.

When ran within the project, everything works fine. However, Hibernate fails to map the entity when run from outside the project.

---

CommonDB.java (part of the maven package meta1203-data)

```java
package com.meta1203.microservices;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class CommonDB <C extends BaseEntity> {
    private Configuration cfg;
    private SessionFactory sf;
    private Session session;
    private Class<C> c;

    public CommonDB(Class<C> anoClass) {
        String jdbcUrl = String.format(
                "jdbc:mysql://%s/%s",
                System.getenv("DB_URL"),
                System.getenv("DB_NAME"));

        cfg = new Configuration()
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", jdbcUrl)
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", System.getenv("DB_USERNAME"))
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", System.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"))

                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size", "1")
                .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect")
                .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update")
                .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")
                .addAnnotatedClass(anoClass.getClass());

        c = anoClass;
    }

    public void open() {
        sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        session = sf.openSession();
    }

    public void close() {
        session.close();
        sf.close();
    }

    public C findOneBy(String field, String o) {
        String query = "select u from " + c.getSimpleName() + " u where u." + field + " = :id";

        return session.createQuery(query, c).setParameter("id", o).getSingleResult();
    }
 // other CRUD functions
}
```

TestDB.java (part of the maven package meta1203-userservice)

```java
package com.meta1203.microservices.user;

import com.meta1203.microservices.CommonDB;
import com.meta1203.microservices.user.model.User;

public class TestDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestDB tdb = new TestDB();
        CommonDB<User> db = new CommonDB<User>(User.class);
        db.open();

        User hunter = db.findOneBy("username", "hunter");
        System.out.println(hunter.getUsername());
        System.out.println(db.countBy("username", "hunter"));

        db.close();
    }
}
```

User.java (part of the maven package meta1203-userservice)

```java
package com.meta1203.microservices.user.model;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.meta1203.microservices.BaseEntity;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {
    private String username;

    private String textNotificationList;
    private String emailNotificationList;

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Long> ignoredAlerts;
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Long> clients;

    // to be parsed with DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME
    private String lastItineraryUpdate;

     // getters and setters
}
```

parent's pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.meta1203</groupId>
    <artifactId>meta1203-services</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.meta1203</groupId>
            <artifactId>meta1203-data</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <modules>
        <module>meta1203-userservice</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

---

```
Sep 07, 2019 2:36:13 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {[WORKING]}
Sep 07, 2019 2:36:13 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Sep 07, 2019 2:36:13 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
Sep 07, 2019 2:36:14 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Sep 07, 2019 2:36:14 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@329dbdbf] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Sep 07, 2019 2:36:14 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [select u from User u where u.username = :id]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:729)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:104)
    at com.meta1203.microservices.CommonDB.findOneBy(CommonDB.java:72)
    at com.meta1203.microservices.user.TestDB.main(TestDB.java:12)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [select u from User u where u.username = :id]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:720)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3695)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3584)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whelp, I found out what was going on. My galaxy brain decided to do `addAnnotatedClass(anoClass.getClass())` on a Class object, so I was trying to declare java.lang.Class as a Hibernate Entity... Oh well, I'm just an idiot. Changed it to just `addAnnotatedClass(anoClass)` and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {
```

Your entity is called User but its mapped to a table called users.

Either change the entity to Users or table to user.

That should do it.

Comment: Doesn't work, still getting ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Users is not mapped [select u from Users u where u.username = :id]``` on execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        for (Class cls : getEntityClassesFromPackage("com.example.hib.entities")) {
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(cls);
        }
```